# Cannot Execute Javascript XPath queries on created document

Tags: javascript, xpath, xhtml, document

#### Problem

I'm creating a document with javascript and I'd like to execute XPath queries on this document.

- I've tried this in safari/chrome
- I've read up on createDocument / xpath searches and it really seems like this code should work
- At this point it seems like it may be a webkit bug

#### My requirements:

- I can use innerHTML() to setup the document
- I can execute xpath searches w tagnames

#### The code:

If you copy/paste the following into the webkit inspector, you should be able to repro.

```
function search(query, root) {  
  var result = null;
  result = document.evaluate(query, root, null, 7,null);

  var nodes = [];
  var node_count = result.snapshotLength;

  for(var i = 0; i < node_count; i++) {
    nodes.push(result.snapshotItem(i));
  }

  return nodes;
}

x = document.implementation.createDocument('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'html', 'HTML');  

body = x.createElement('body');
body.innerHTML = "<span class='mything'><a></a></span>";

xdoc = x.documentElement; //html tag
xdoc.appendChild(body);

console.log(search(".", xdoc));     // --> [<html>​…​</html>​]
console.log(search("/*", xdoc));    // --> [<html>​…​</html>​]
console.log(search("/html", xdoc)); // --> []
```

#### Best Guess

So I can definitely search using XPath, but I cannot search using tagnames. Is there something silly I'm missing about the namespace?

Comment: Why pass `7` to the result type parameter and not `0`? Have you looked at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript#XPathResult_Defined_Constants

Comment: It appears to be a problem (or a bug) with the document you're creating in JavaScript. If you execute the same function on a normal document (like this page), it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
console.log(search("//html", xdoc));
```

I'm not familiar with Safari specifically, but the problem might be that Safari is adding another node above HTML or something.  If this was the case, the first two queries might be showing you that node plus it's children, which would make it look like they're working properly, while the third query would fail because there wouldn't be a root=>HTML node.

Just a thought.